# Combining and listing multiple Core Data properties into one array - Specifically for SwiftUI map kit

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data, mapkit

Im having an issue working with the @Fetchrequest property wrapper and combining all the data into one array. Specifically needed, because the Mapkit API only takes one array for it annotations (annotationItems: )

I have the following arrays:

```
 @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: OrgEntity.all()) private var orgs
 @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: PersonEntity.all()) private var people
 @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: TaskEntity.all()) private var tasks
```

And I want to display annotations for every object in these three arrays, but I cant figure out a way to implement that. Using just the org property for examples works fine, but how do I list all three?

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $vm.region, showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: orgs,  annotationContent: { org in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: org.lat, longitude: org.long)) {
                    MapAnnotationPin()
                        .scaleEffect()
                }
            })
```

Here's my full code

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreData

struct MapView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @EnvironmentObject private var vm: MapViewModel
    
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: OrgEntity.all()) private var orgs
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: PersonEntity.all()) private var people
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: TaskEntity.all()) private var tasks
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
           // Map(coordinateRegion: $vm.region, showsUserLocation: true)
            Map(coordinateRegion: $vm.region, showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: orgs,  annotationContent: { org in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: org.lat, longitude: org.long)) {
                    MapAnnotationPin()
                        .scaleEffect()
                }
            })
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .onAppear {
                    vm.checkIfLocationServicesEnabled()
                }
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                header
                .padding()
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack {
                    if vm.selectedEntity != nil {
                        MapCardView(entity: vm.selectedEntity!)
                            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 20)
                            .padding()
                            .transition(.asymmetric(
                                insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
                                removal: .move(edge: .leading)))
                    }
                }
                
                backButton
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use an "Abstract Entity" to combine them or a Parent Entity with relationships, or have an Annotations Entity and have relationships with these 3 entities

Answer (score 0):

You could merge them into a computed property of locations

```
var locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
    orgs.map { 
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.lat, longitude: $0.long)
    } +
    people.map { 
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.lat, longitude: $0.long)
    } +
    tasks.map { 
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.lat, longitude: $0.long)
    }
}
```

I used CLLocationCoordinate2D as the element here but MapAnnotation might work equally well.